# executing anonymous functions created using JavaScript eval()

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a function and its contents as a string.

```
var funcStr = "function() { alert('hello'); }";
```

Now, I do an eval() to actually get that function in a variable.

```
var func = eval(funcStr);
```

If I remember correctly, in Chrome and Opera, simply calling

```
func();
```

invoked that function and the alert was displayed.

But, in other browsers it wasn't the case. nothing happened.

I don't want an arguement about which is the correct method, but how can I do this? I want to be able to call variable(); to execute the function stored in that variable.

Comment: I am wondering why you need an anonymous function represented as a string literal, as opposed to simply having a named function?

Comment: FYI: I am defining my own script for my web app. I am writing an interpreter and need to construct JS functions on the fly and then create actual executable functions out of them.

Comment: why wouldn't you write the interpreter in the traditional way?

Comment: I don't know how to write it in the "traditional way".. I found this easier. If you can clue me in to how its done "traditionally" it'd be nice.

Comment: Try wrapping the function in parentheses before passing the string into `eval`.  ```var funcStr = "( function() { alert('hello'); } )";```

Comment: @PeopleAskingWhy? -- Because I want to learn the limitations of the language, and explore its outter edges, so I understand it well enough that instead of asking these questions, I know how to answer them.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

How about this?

```
var func = new Function('alert("hello");');
```

To add arguments to the function:

```
var func = new Function('what', 'alert("hello " + what);');
func('world'); // hello world
```

Do note that functions are objects and can be assigned to any variable as they are:

```
var func = function () { alert('hello'); };
var otherFunc = func;
func = 'funky!';

function executeSomething(something) {
    something();
}
executeSomething(otherFunc); // Alerts 'hello'
```

Comment: This is both an elegant way to do it, and works in all browsers. Thanks :)

Answer (score 15):

IE cannot `eval` functions (Presumably for security reasons).

The best workaround is to put the function in an array, like this:

```
var func = eval('[' + funcStr + ']')[0];
```

Comment: Yes it can. However, function literal are not statements, so they need parentheses around them, it's cleaner than your array solution

Comment: @Juan: Wrong; it cannot.  Try `javascript:alert(eval('( function() { return 3; } )'));`

Comment: My bad, I suggested using parentheses instead of your array solution, I didn't realize that didn't work in IE

Answer (score 8):

I realize this is old, but it was the only valid result coming up in my google searches for evaluating anonymous javascript function strings.

I finally figured out how to do it from a post on the jquery google group.

```
eval("false||"+data)
```

where data is your function string like "function() { return 123; }"

So far, I have only tried this in IE8 and FF8 (the browsers on my personal computer), but I believe jquery uses this internally so it should work just about everywhere.

Comment: I don't understand why everyone else is seems to not have this issue. This is gold, thanks!

Comment: We can do it also on this way `eval('!1||'+funcBody);`

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
var funcStr = "var func = function() { alert('hello'); }";

eval(funcStr);

func();
```

Comment: hey, Thanks that worked! But it looks a bit weird to do it that way :D.

Answer (score 4):

Use the eval like this :

```
var func = eval('(' + funcStr + ')');
```

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but I'm pretty sure that applies only to objects.

Comment: Also, whether its the right way or the wrong way..., it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Tried this on IE and didn't work `eval ('(function(){return 'Yay'})')()`. However, `eval ('[function(){return 'Yay'}][0]')()` worked

Answer (score 4):

We solved this problem by preparing universal function parser that convert string to real JavaScript function:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.parseFunction != 'function') {
    String.prototype.parseFunction = function () {
        var funcReg = /function *\(([^()]*)\)[ \n\t]*{(.*)}/gmi;
        var match = funcReg.exec(this.replace(/\n/g, ' '));

        if(match) {
            return new Function(match[1].split(','), match[2]);
        }

        return null;
    };
}
```

examples of usage:

```
var func = 'function (a, b) { return a + b; }'.parseFunction();
alert(func(3,4));

func = 'function (a, b) { alert("Hello from function initiated from string!"); }'.parseFunction();
func();
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/xck9tvnc/3/) is jsfiddle

Comment: You're a genius! With some modifications to strip comments your function saved my day, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This is also ok.

```
var func = eval("_="+funcStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

EVAL without eval()...

```
function evalEx(code){
  var result,D=document,S=D.createElement('script'),
  H=D.head||D.getElementsByTagName['head'][0],
  param=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  code='function evalWE(){'+code+'}';
  S.innerText===''?S.innerText=code:S.textContent=code;
  H.appendChild(S);
  result=evalWE.apply(this,param);
  H.removeChild(S);
  return result
}
```

Usage Example:

```
ABC=evalEx('return "ABC"');
nine=evalEx('return arguments[1]+arguments[2]',4,5);
```

Comment: haha, you just gave me the reason why Google Packaged Apps disallow inline javascript in the HTML: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of defining a function as a string, `eval()`ing it, and passing in a parameter while immediately invoking the function (and then dumping the result to the console):

`console.log('eval: %s', eval("(function(foo) { return foo.bar; })")({"bar": "12345"}));`

This produces output like the following.

`eval: 12345`

Answer (score -1):

What also works is

```
var myFunc = function(myParam){
   // function body here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[function-serialization-tools](https://github.com/llambda/function-serialization-tools) provides a function, s2f(), that takes a string representation of a function and returns it as a function.