# underscore.js precompiled templates using

Tags: underscore.js, template-engine, precompile, underscore.js-templating

I want to use precompiled underscore.js templates. I use `_.template().source` and save result in file. But I don't understand, how to use this templates. Precompiled templates is strings, and I can't cast it to a function. I try to use `eval`, but it always return parse error.

For example:

```
<div>
    <% for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ %>
        <div><%=i%></div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Standart using:

```
_.template(tpl).({});
```

Result:

```
<div>

    <div>0</div>

    <div>1</div>

    <div>2</div>

    <div>3</div>

    <div>4</div>

</div>
```

Precompilation:

```
_.template(tpl).source
```

Precompiled template:

```
"function(obj){
var __t,__p='',__j=Array.prototype.join,print=function(){__p+=__j.call(arguments,'');};
with(obj||{}){
__p+='<div>\n\t';
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
__p+='\n\t\t<div>'+
((__t=(i))==null?'':__t)+
'</div>\n\t';
 } 
__p+='\n</div>\n';
}
return __p;
}"
```

Running precompiled template:

```
var a = eval(tplc);
a({});
```

Error:

```
Error
line: 1
message: "Parse error"
sourceId: 139746789246216
__proto__: SyntaxError
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1271572/1726295) solution. I can't say that this is elegant solution, but it works. 
For my example:

```
var a = eval('[' + tplc + ']')[0];
a({});
```

Comment: `eval` is never the answer.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use eval." Now they have two problems, five security issues and one undebuggable mess.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `source` attribute returns the compiled template as a string. You can write that string to a file which defines a JavaScript object literal something like this:

```
window.JST = { };
JST.some_name = function(obj){ ... };
// The rest of the compiled template functions go here
```

Then, load that into the browser like any other JavaScript file and you'll end up with a bunch of compiled template functions in `JST`:

```
var html = JST.some_name(data);
```

You can structure the `JST` definition however you want of course, that just a simple way to illustrate the overall approach.

Remember that whether a string is just some text to be manipulated like any other blob of text (such as writing it to a file) or if it is JavaScript source code depends on who is interpreting the string.